# Can there be nested toggle?

Tags: usability, toggle

Can we have a nested toggle, which would function like "Select All" or vice versa? It's similar to a check box, but will be shown using toggle button.

But there is a problem: If I've selected a partial list of items, how will I represent it?  On/Off State or color change, which is neither on or off?

[image: Example Wireframe]

Comment: Can you give a visual representation of what you are asking?

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov added wireframe for reference.

Comment: This looks like a UX nightmare. Back to basics, what are you trying to achieve? What's the use case for this? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Its function is like a bookmark. It will behave like select all/deselect (Option1 heading).

Comment: @DarrylGodden I know it's a nightmare.:(

Comment: But you have some controls with the same value, unless that's just a lazy example?

Comment: Its functionality is like check box with select all option at the beginning.

Comment: What is the semantics of setting the switch labelled "Option 1" to *on*? Is this configuration equivalent to setting all the nested switches to *on*?

Comment: It is the developer within you that says '_yes_' to nested toggles. Try to visualize the whole set up, as a user. As a user, if I see so many of these toggles, all that comes to my mind are buttons on a flight cockpit, and god knows what they are, and I wouldn't even bother finding out.

Comment: I would like to know from UX perspective is it good practice?

Comment: I don't think this is very pleasing to the eye. Just think over it, and use the input from other users, and you'll be able to come up with a better visualization for the same. Don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

You could clearly indicate that the overall toggle will toggle everything on or off depending on the previous state, just like a select all.

You can also have maybe a numerical indication of how many is on. Example off of your screenshot would be something like "11/20"